# Is it possible send New Year Greeting Wishes to App Users using Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

My app is live and i have app users device ID token.

Is it possible to send New Year Greeting as a Push Notification to all users, who have installed my app ?

Is it possible to send Group or Individual Push Notification to App users'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a group push notification in APNS.

In order to send the same message to all your users you should send an individual message to each of the device tokens you collected, even if the payload of all those messages is identical.